# jQuery DataTables: comparing two columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm running the latest version of the jQuery DataTables and using the server side option. I'm running into a problem when trying to complete a simple compare of two columns of data.
This `DOCS_VER` value in column 5 below will contain a 0 or a 1:

```
{ "data": "DOCS_VER" },
```

And the `DOCS_WAIT` database value in column 6 will contain some kind of text like "Refered" which comes from the database.

```
{ "data": "DOCS_WAIT" },
```

My rendering script is shown below and runs only without the `else if` option. I cannot figure out how to add the additional check for the `DOCS_WAIT` option.

```
{
  "targets": -4,
  "data": "DOCS_VER",
  "render": function (data, type, row) {
    var color = 'black';
    if (data == 1) {
      color = 'green';
      ColorCheck = 'VALIDATED';
      IconChoice = ' fa fa-check-square-o';
    } else if (row[6] == 1) {
      color = 'orange';
      ColorCheck = 'WAITING';
      IconChoice = 'fa fa-spin fa-spinner';
    } else {
      color = 'red';
      ColorCheck = 'NON-VALID';
      IconChoice = 'fa fa-exclamation-triangle';
    }
    return '<span style="color: ' + color + '"><i class="' + IconChoice + '"></i> ' + ColorCheck+ '</span>';
  },
},
```

Anyone have any ideas how to properly check row 6 to see if it's a 1 or 0?

Comment: are you getting an error in the console? have you tried setting a breakpoint to see what the row argument looks like? Or a console.log?

Comment: Nothing shows in the error console, yet I am sure this is because "undefined" is getting passed which would not equal 1.

Comment: okay...the next step is to determine what "row" is. Sometimes it might be an array, but it can also be an object, in which case it might be `row.DOCS_WAIT` or something like that instead of `row[6]`. You really need to use either a debugger or a console log to make sure that `row` is what you think it is. You can also do a console.log(arguments) if it turns out row isn't actually the right argument for what you want

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all of your help.

Looks like the following code worked perfectly.

```
                     {
                    "targets": -4,                          
                    "render": function ( data, type, row )
                        {
                            var color = 'black';
                            if (row['DOCS_VER'] == 1) {
                            color = 'green';
                            ColorCheck = 'VALIDATED';
                            IconChoice = ' fa fa-check-square-o';
                        } 
                            else if (row['DOCS_WAIT'] == 1) {
                            color = 'orange';
                            ColorCheck = 'WAITING';
                            IconChoice = 'fa fa-spin fa-spinner';
                        } 
                            else  {
                            color = 'red';
                            ColorCheck = 'NON-VALID';
                            IconChoice = 'fa fa-exclamation-triangle';
                        }

                        return '<span style="color:' + color + '"><i class="' + IconChoice + '"></i> ' + ColorCheck+ '</span>';
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `row['DOCS_VER']` to reference another property in the data set if your data is an array of objects.